# Guardar backup de mysql con un timestamp

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente comando para ejecutarlo en cmd. La idea es que realice un backup de una base de datos `mysql` con un `timestamp` como nombre

```
mysqldump -uroot -hlocalhost -pSI app > %homepath%\Desktop\Backups\%date:/=%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.sql
```

sin embargo esto es lo que retorna:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "10072019_11-30-25.sql"
```

Obviamente no tengo una tabla con ese nombre, pero eso debería ser el nombre del archivo. ¿Que puedo hacer? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| find "."') do set DateTime=%%a

set Yr=%DateTime:~0,4%
set Mon=%DateTime:~4,2%
set Day=%DateTime:~6,2%
set Hr=%DateTime:~8,2%
set Min=%DateTime:~10,2%
set Sec=%DateTime:~12,2%

cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump --databases -u root -pSI app >C:%homepath%\Desktop\Backups\Backup-%Day%_%Mon%_%Yr%_at_%Hr%-%Min%-%Sec%.sql
```

Comment: Al final lo logré con este .bat. Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este comando, para ver si te da el mismo error:

```
mysqldump --databases -u root --password='tupassword' 'nombredelabasedatos'>C:\respaldoLocal_%FECHA%.sql
```

Lo que está con comillas debes modificarlo y quitarle las comillas.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96007/discussion-on-answer-by-osubarudo-guardar-backup-de-mysql-con-un-timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te la dejo con los saltos de linea, para que no te confundas:

echo off
set FECHA=%date:/=-%
echo %FECHA%
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\
mysqldump --databases -u root -pSI app >C:\BackUp_%FECHA%.sql

Esto yo lo pongo en archivo .bat y lo ejecuto como administrador.

Comment: https://ibb.co/fX8QxRT muestra el script y el archivo que se crea

Comment: Intenta con otra ruta de destino, como por ejemplo:C:\BackUp_%FECHA%.sql

Comment: es exactamente el mismo resultado

Comment: Estoy seguro que es problema de sintaxis, hice pruebas y me pasaba lo mismo que a ti y lo solucione con el scrip que te dejé.

Comment: Me di cuenta que genera el archivo con el tamaño que debería, es decir que posee data. pero no se genera .sql

Comment: Ábrelo y fijate si tiene codigo sql.

Comment: si lo tiene, pero no es .sql

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto:
[pathmysql]\mysqldump.exe -hlocalhost -uroot -ppass basededatos > C:\bkp_3.2.2.6__%date:/=%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.sql

Comment: mismo problema. me genera un archivo no sql con el nombre de ''bkp_3.2.2.6__mie'

Comment: al ponerlo en la cmd retorna esto:  Got error: 1049: Unknown database '10072019_13-02-16.sql'

Comment: https://ibb.co/kg5v6ZW a mi me funciona

Comment: debes cambiar [basededatos] por el nombre de tu base de datos

Comment: mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "10072019_13-23-37.sql" mismo problema

Comment: podrias pasarme como estas escribiendo

Comment: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe -hlocalhost -uroot -pSI app > C:%homepath%\Desktop\Backups\bkp_3.2.2.6__%date:/=%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.sql

Comment: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe -hlocalhost -uroot -pSI app > C:\%homepath%\Desktop\Backups\bkp_3.2.2.6__%date:/=%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.sql  prueba

Comment: O bien prueba con un path explicito C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe -hlocalhost -uroot -pSI app > C:\Users\TUUSUARIO\Desktop\Backups\bkp_3.2.2.6__%date:/=%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.sql recuerda cambiar TUUSUARIO por el tuyo

Comment: ambas opciones me retornan lo mismo mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "10072019_13-30-50"

Comment: echo test >C:\Users\Osmar\bkp_3.2.2.6__%date:/=%_%time:~0,2%-%tim
e:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.sql  prueba esto solo, reemplaza el usuario Osmar por el tuyo

Comment: Couldn't find table: "10072019_14-%tim"

Comment: espera ese ultimo que te pase fue para solo crear el archivo el texto test, solo proba esto sin el mysqldump entendes? asi como te pase en la imagen

Comment: crea el archivo bkp_3.2.2.6__mie

Comment: podrias pasar una foto de lo que estas ejecutando y el resultado

Comment: https://ibb.co/nrM6Tqw
https://ibb.co/3YSrGqr

Comment: tiene un espacio en la setencia perdon a mi se me fue echo test >C:\Users\Osmar\bkp_%date:/=%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.sql asi seria. ese 3.2.2.6 no es necesario era solo para separar

Comment: https://ibb.co/TkTFGph eso retorna

Comment: te olvidaste del signo >  antes del C:\User ....

Comment: https://ibb.co/T4LtZSf

Comment: me es raro que no te salga, prueba asi abriendo un cmd nuevo, ten cuidado no incluir enter o espacios, esta. echo test > bkp__%date:/=%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.sql

Comment: mismo resultado

Comment: algo estas haciendo mal, mira si te equivocas un espacio o una coma falla.

Comment: no tiene espacios ni comas, mi teoría es que la fecha en algún lado tiene un punto, lo que hace que el archivo no se guarde bien